# Testing models using Simpletest and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, simpletest

I am new to the PHP world and I am trying to setup some tests for my models. I am using CodeIgniter and Simpletest. I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Model' not found...
```

I assume that this happens because my model extends from `CI_Model`. `CI_Model` class has the following code:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

So my question is: how can I test my models using Simpletest?

Answer (score 0):

Your test script needs to configure the necessary environment. In this case, you can define `BASEPATH`:

```
define('BASEPATH', '/your/path');
```

Comment: Doing the following still produces the same error: DEFINE('BASEPATH', '../../');
require_once('../application/models/user.php');

class TestOfUserModel extends UnitTestCase {

Comment: @PmanAce For some unknown reason, I used caps in my original post. `define` should be lowercase. Also ensure that the definition occurs before the inclusion of the script that performs the check.